SQL Server Standard and Enterprise editions in AlwaysOn Availability Groups
Can two different versions of SQL Servers participate in AlwaysOn Availability Groups?
I am specifically talking about SQL Server 2019 Standard and SQL Server 2019 Enterprise.


Can two different versions of SQL Servers participate in AlwaysOn Availability Groups?
I am specifically talking about SQL Server 2019 Standard and SQL Server 2019 Enterprise.

Nope.
AlwaysOn Availability Groups is an Enterprise Edition-only feature, as mentioned in the Editions and Supported Features docs. So even two servers running Standard Edition would not be able to partake in an AlwaysOn Availability Group.
As noted by David Browne, Standard Edition offers a similar feature called Basic Availability Groups, but again, you can't mix Editions with either feature.

Standard Edition supports Basic Availability Groups, but still you can't mix them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16
